# Django count nested m2m objects

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have 3 models -

```
class A(models.Model):
    ...
    b = models.ManyToManyField(B, related_name="related_a")

class B(models.Model):
    ...

class Entries(models.Model):
    ...
    b = models.ForeignKey(B, related_name="entries")
```

I need to loop over all `A` objects and show the count of `entries` for each `b` in A, along with other fields in A. What would be the most efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it done in 2 queries:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Prefetch

qs = B.objects.annotate(entry_count=Count('entries'))
a_list = A.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('b', queryset=qs))
```

I hope I've got all related names right. You can access the counts like this:

```
for a in a_list:
    for b_item in a.b:
        print(b_item.entry_count)
```

Comment: I was thinking of doing the same thing. Thanks for validation :)